# Changing sprites' black pixels' color in HTML5 Canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a little HTML5 Canvas game project. During gameplay, I sometimes need to make multiple sprites' black pixels constantly "glow" from pure black, to light grey, and back to pure black again (then repeating for a while).

This happens in multiple steps (7 in total), so it goes something like pure black -> dark grey -> grey -> etc.

None of the sprites' pixels other than the black ones should be affected.

[Here's an example of a sprite's animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg1PS.png)

[Here's an example of what the glowing should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfwqi.png)

This has to happen constantly while the sprite itself is animating. The glowing is on a separate timer from sprite's animations, so at any point I could have any combination of animation frame and "glow color".

Also, the glow timer is the same for all sprites that are affected by it. So if sprite 1 has its glow light grey, so should sprite 2, sprite 3, etc.

I'm aware I could get the sprite's image data, loop through every pixel and change the black pixels individually to different values, doing something like this:

```
var map = ctx.getImageData(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.width, sprite.height);

for (var p = 0; p < map.data.length; p += 4) {
    if (map.data[p] === 0 && map.data[p + 1] === 0 && map.data[p + 2] === 0) {
        // If black pixel, swap with glow's current color
        map.data[p] = map.data[p + 1] = map.data[p + 2] = currentGlow;
}

ctx.putImageData(map, sprite.x, sprite.y);
```

But I'm concerned about performance issues this could bring. I can possibly have a good amount of different sprites with the glow effect at the same time (100+), and doing all of this for each of them individually in a game loop seems pretty inefficient.

What would be the best way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

For black chroma-key, there is a nice SVG filter which allows to convert luminance to alpha.

```css
img { filter: url(#getBlack); }

body { background: salmon; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="getBlack">
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg1PS.png">
```

Good, but it also affects other colors (white => opaque, gray => semi-opaque, black => transparent).
So we need to apply an other filter which will act as a threshold on the Alpha channel.

```css
img { filter: url(#getBlack); }
body { background: salmon; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="getBlack">
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg1PS.png">
```

But now all our pixels are black, except where there were black pixels... That's still not what we needed.
Well, we can use a bit of compositing (we'll do it from the Canvas API) to achieve our goal:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image;
let color = 0;
let inc = 2;
img.onload = init;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg1PS.png";

function init() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  // clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // first pass, draw the scene normally
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

  // second pass, keep only non-black pixels
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
  ctx.filter = 'url(#getBlack)';
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0); // use the canvas as source
  ctx.filter = 'none';

  // third pass, draw behind actual value for were-black
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#" + (color.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).repeat(3)
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // clean
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  // dirty increment color
  if (
    ((color += inc) > 255 && (color = 255)) ||
    (color < 0 && !(color = 0))
  ) {
    inc *= -1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body { background: salmon; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="getBlack">
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: salmon"></canvas>
```

---

Now, while `filter()` *should* be easier to optimize for browsers than CPU intensive `getImageData`, I didn't made extensive tests to confirm or infirm this, and I suspect that different inputs will anyway show different results, so at the end, you are responsible for choosing the best way for your app.

But anyway, you may need to perform ImageData manipulation since `filter` is unfortunately still not supported everywhere, so one thing that you might want to consider, moreover when it seems you are using pixel-art sprites, is downsampling.
Instead of doing the chroma-key over the full-size canvas, you can reproduce your canvas on a smaller one, perform the chroma-key on this smaller version, and use compositing after-ward from the sub-sampled chroma result.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image;
let color = 0;
let inc = 2;
img.onload = init;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Monochrome_pixelated_head.png";

const smallCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const smallCtx = smallCanvas.getContext('2d');

document.body.append(smallCanvas);


function init() {
  canvas.width = img.width * 5;
  canvas.height = img.height * 5;
  smallCanvas.width = canvas.width / 10;
  smallCanvas.height = canvas.height / 10;
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  smallCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  draw();
}

function draw() {
  // clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  smallCtx.clearRect(0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height);

  // first pass, draw the scene normally
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

  // second pass, do the chroma-key on the small canvas
  smallCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height); // use the canvas as source
  // get the small ImageData
  const data = smallCtx.getImageData(0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height);
  // by using an Uint32Array, we can work one pixel at a time
  // (4 times less iterations than with Uint8Clamped)
  const arr = new Uint32Array(data.data.buffer);
  const currentColor = parseInt('FF' + (color.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).repeat(3), 16);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === 0xFF000000) arr[i] = currentColor;
  }
  // apply modified ImageData
  smallCtx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
  // now draw big
  ctx.drawImage(smallCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // dirty increment color
  if (
    ((color += inc) > 255 && (color = 255)) ||
    (color < 0 && !(color = 0))
  ) {
    inc *= -1;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body { background: salmon; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="getBlack">
      <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="255"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: salmon"></canvas>
```

But if it is really the case then you may even consider doing all your drawings directly from the downsampled canvas and only resize as the last step.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The last solution seems to work pretty good for my purposes. The one thing I failed to mention though, was that I kept my background scene on a different layer that was drawn underneath.All my entity sprites were drawn on top of that with transparency around them. So I end up with all my sprites properly glowing but the background gets obscured by the black rectangle. I guess the best thing to do here would be to keep the background on the same canvas layer. I suppose it's probably more efficient? Luckily none of the background tiles have black pixels, either.

Comment: Another thing I should mention, I don't always want to make every sprite's black pixels glow. Only the sprites of the actors that are "powered up". The only solution I could think of would be to only draw the sprites that should be effected first, pass through the scene with `filter()`, and then draw the other sprites on top of that. This might work, but then the issue is the sprites might overlap, and the glowing ones aren't necessarily the ones that should be on top.